# Shorten file names in React build directory to less than 32 chars

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, esp32, spiffs

This is going to sound really dumb but I need a way to shorten file names of my React build folder because I need to upload my React app to a SPIFFS file system on an ESP32 that only supports file names up to 32 characters (including folders).

I think an easy way would be to get rid of the hashes at the end of the files but I don't know how to do that.

So how can I shorten the file names of a React app?

Comment: Did you find out? I've got the same problem.

Comment: yepp. Figure out how you can use webpack and setup your own react pipeline. Its really not as hard as it sounds. Also make sure you build in release mode (NODE_ENV="production") and you tar gz your files before uploading them to the esp, so the browser can unzip them, in order to save space

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, don't get rid of hashes entirely, they're incredibly useful for cache invalidation. I also recommend not starting your own build from scratch unless you know what you're doing; CRA is really good at this stuff, even if it does throw in a bunch of stuff you probably will never use. (Vite templates are also a good solution, see the other answer and especially the comments there).

If you're set on using CRA, first run `npm run eject`. This means you'll now be in charge of your own config rather than relying entirely on create-react-app, but you need this to change your Webpack config (or you could use react-app-rewired, customize-cra, or some other similar option).

Change [the output](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/0a827f69ab0d2ee3871ba9b71350031d8a81b7ae/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L221) to use a shorter contenthash (maybe 4) and change out `[name]` for something shorter, like the result of a random character generator that only returns two chars. If you always just produce one bundle, use a static name rather than something dynamic (in brackets). If you don't want chunks, delete the chunk related config.

And if you want the simplest possible solution, still start from `create-react-app` and ejecting, but change all of `output` to something like this:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto')
const id = crypto.randomBytes(2).toString('hex')
output: {
  filename: `x.${id}.js`
}
```

And definitely gzip the output, with a Make target or shell script or [a package](https://github.com/jnsjknn/compress-create-react-app).

Answer (score 1):

I used [vite](https://vitejs.dev/) with [preact](https://preactjs.com/) to create my React for ESP32 project (`npm create vite@latest my_project --template preact`). vite uses [rollup](https://rollupjs.org) as it's bundler and rollup has simple configuration options to change its bundling strategy.

To create filenames compatible with ESP32 SPIFFS (i.e. the full path not longer than 31 characters), I used the following config options in `vite.config.js`:

```
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        assetFileNames: "a/[hash:10][extname]",
        chunkFileNames: "c/[hash:10].js",
        entryFileNames: "e/[hash:10].js"
      }
    }
  },
  ...
```

You can read about the rollup configuration options [here](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/).

Comment: I don't think this is a valid answer, as you're not even attempting to give instructions for the tool the person is using (`create-react-app`). How you could configure `vite` to do this is an answer for another questions.

Comment: @rschristian The question is about ESP32 and SPIFFS, where you have only a 4MB flash, of which (assuming you use OTA) you have at most ~1.3MB for your SPIFFS partition. `create-react-app` by itself consumes ~500KiB, and then there are the problems associated with filename lengths described in the question. In contrast, vite-preact consumes ~18KiB and via rollup has a mechanism to easily reduce filenames. I agree with you that this doesn't address the question directly, but doing so is _the wrong way_ as space is such a major concern on ESP32. My answer presents a much more pragmatic approach.

Comment: @par agreed! I think it would be great if you include the explanation of cra vs vite in your answer itself.

Comment: Here's a great YouTube video on using React with ESP32: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9n32nxrzug